# how can I set eventID in android calendar

Tags: android, insert, calendar

I want to know whether there is a method that we can set eventID during insert event into calendar using Intent?

Comment: hey, just check my answer.

Comment: Seems not,when use Intent,although it will not report error,but ID is not set actually,eg.intent.putExtra(Events._ID,123),after insert,when query,I still get ID 0

Comment: Just try id value is 12345, and let me know

Comment: I have tried it.When I use Intent,eg. Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, Events.CONTENT_URI); it cannot insert eventID;but when I set Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values); I can set the eventID,but I do want eventID when using INTENT,is there any method?

Comment: I think you can. But need to research something

Answer (score 1):

Put below line when you add new event.

```
values.put(Events._ID, YOUR EVENT ID.longValue());
```

Events._ID consists value _id, its just for your information.